# Running 32bit .NET application in VMWare in 64bit OS

Tags: asp.net, windows, vmware

I was compiling code asp.net C# in my VMWare setup on XP 32 bit running VS 2010 .net 3.5. My host OS is Windows 7 64 bit. However when I click the RUN button, I keep getting access violation /  unhandled exception.

Other developers on the same project does not have any issue. Their setup is 32bit on Windows XP. Could this be because of my setup?
AccessViolationException was unhandled.
"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

I am new in .NET so I am not sure where is all the print stack trace if there is any

Comment: Have you looked at the stacktrace for the exceptions ?

Comment: I would advise that you expand your question because you're not providing enough information for anyone to realistically help you. This usually leads to a protracted and frustrating round of requests in the comments for more information by other users who **really do want to help you**. For example, include in the question: code snippets/samples, the API you're using, stack traces, screen shots etc. When you've done this, flag to have your question re-opened. Please also take the time to [read this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Thanks.

Comment: Unless you are attempting to use GPU hardware, it is extremely unlikely that the problem is because you are running in a virtual machine.

Comment: I am using a GPU hardware. How is this related because my aspx does not use any thing graphic intensive.